# Flutter - Get Product details API integration using GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm trying to connect the API to the UI in a flutter.
I created Json class and product controls. When I try to create the product list view, I get the below errors.

Error lines:

```
1. itemCount: productController.productList.length,
2. productController.productList[index].imageLink,
3. productController.productList[index].title,
```

Errors:

1. The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Rx'.
2. The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Rx'.
3. The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Rx'.

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice/commonmodule/AppColor.dart';
import 'package:practice/commonmodule/AppString.dart';
import 'package:practice/productmodule/controllers/product_controller.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ProductListView extends StatelessWidget {
 final ProductController productController = Get.put(ProductController());

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(AppString.productList),
  ),
  body: Obx(
    () {
      if (productController.isLoading.value)
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      else
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: productController.productList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 150,
                      height: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 8, 8),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        child: Image.network(
                          productController.productList[index].imageLink,
                          width: 150,
                          height: 100,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          color: AppColor.bluecolor,
                          colorBlendMode: BlendMode.color,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          productController.productList[index].title,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          productController.productList[index].description,
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: AppColor.grey),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          productController.productList[index].price,
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: AppColor.grey),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  color: AppColor.grey200,
                  height: 2,
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what the error message suggests, it seems like your `productList` of `ProductController` is a type of `Rx`. So, in this case, you have add `.value` after the product list.

1. `productController.productList.value.length`
2. `productController.productList.value[index].imageLink`
3. `productController.productList.value[index].title`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried but the same error occurs. 1.productController.productList.value.length
2. productController.productList.value[index].imageLink
3. productController.productList.value[index].title

Comment: May i know how you declare `productList` in your `ProductController`? I presumably for the error to persist is that the type declare for the `productList`.